# regex with repeated group names

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-regex

I'm trying to make a regex where I have some duplicated group names, for instance, in the example below I want to find the values of `ph`, `A` and `B` such that if I replace them in the `pattern`, I retrieve `string`. I do this using `regex`, as the default `re` library of Python does not allow to duplicate names.

```py
pattern = '(?P<ph>.*?) __ (?P<A>.*?) __ (?P<B>.*?) __ \( (?P<ph>.*?) \-> (?P<A>.*?) = (?P<B>.*?) \) \)'
string = 'y = N __ ( A ` y ) __ ( A ` N ) __ ( y = N -> ( A ` y ) = ( A ` N ) ) )'
match = regex.fullmatch(pattern, string)
for k, v in match.groupdict().items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

And I retrieve the expected output:

```
ph: y = N
A: ( A ` y )
B: ( A ` N )
```

My concern, is that there seems to be some issues with this library, or I'm not using it properly. For instance, if I replace `string` with:
`` string = 'BLABLA __ ( A ` y ) __ ( A ` N ) __ ( y = N -> ( A ` y ) = ( A ` N ) ) )' ``

then the code above provides the exact same values for `ph`, `A` and `B`, ignoring the `BLABLA` prefix at the beginning of `string`, and `match` should be `None` as there are no solutions.

Any ideas?

Note: more precisely, in my problemsI have pairs of patterns/strings `(p_0, s_0) ... (p_n, s_n)` and I have to find a valid match across these pairs, so I concatenated them together with a `__` delimiter, but I am also curious if there is a proper way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignoring the BLABLA prefix"? What are your requirements? `(?P<ph>.*?)` will match `BLABLA` here as it can match any 0 or more chars as few as possible

Comment: So I would like that if you replace the values of `ph`, `A` and `B` then you retrieve exactly `string`, and not a subset of it. I thought this is what `fullmatch` does (at least for the `re` library).

Comment: What is `subst`? And at any rate, `.` matches any char. If you do not want it to match any char but some specific ones, use a specific pattern, do not use `.*?`. What are the **pattern requirements**? I do not ask what task you have.

Comment: so if my pattern is 'A B __ A A' and my string is 'x y __ x x' then the solution will be {A=x, B=y}, but if my string is 'z x x __ y y' then the solution should be "None" as there are no values of A and B that could match this string.

Comment: "*there are no values of A and B that could match this string*" - BUT your `.` matches anything (but line break chars)

Comment: Yes, but it should be consistent with the second match latter in the string no ?

Comment: Here it's like if `ph` was taking different values in the first match and in the second match.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the example. By `subst` I meant `match`

Comment: Do you mean you want the 3 first groups to be equal to the corresponding next 3 groups? `^(?P<ph>.*?) __ (?P<A>.*?) __ (?P<B>.*?) __ \( (?P=ph) \-> (?P=A) = (?P=B) \) \)$`? See https://regex101.com/r/r7IZ77/1

Comment: Ooh, yes I didn't know about the `?P=` backreference thing.. This is exactly what I meant. It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to make sure the first three groups are equal to the corresponding next three groups you need to use *backreferences* to the first three groups rather than use the identically named capturing groups again:

```
^(?P<ph>.*?) __ (?P<A>.*?) __ (?P<B>.*?) __ \( (?P=ph) \-> (?P=A) = (?P=B) \) \)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r7IZ77/1)

Here, `(?P=ph)`, `(?P=A)` and `(?P=B)` are [*named backreferences*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) that match the same text as captured into the groups with corresponding names.

The `^` and `$` anchors are not necessary in your code since you use the `regex.fullmatch` method, but you need them when you test your pattern online in a regex tester.